# Are the vectors incoherent when they have a small dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Assuming the dot product of two vectors $\langle a, b\rangle$ is small but not zero. 
I cannot say they are orthogonal, but I want to say they can be considered more dis-similar than similar.

Is there any better term to describe that situation? 
Can I say they are incoherent?

Comment: Since the angle between the vectors should be almost $90$° (unless the vectors have very small lengths) , what about "almost-orthogonal" ?

Comment: With "similar" , do you mean linear independent ? Vectors with your property are "far away from linear independent", this would be another possibility to describe it.

Comment: @Peter I mean in relation to the similarity value between two vectors which can be measured by their dot product.